# Add XeLaTeX to the command list

Tags: emacs, latex, xelatex

I edit tex file in `Emacs`, and compile it by `C-c C-c`, then `LaTeX` command. Another way to compile it is to use `latex file.tex` in a terminal.

Now, I would like to compile a file with `xelatex`, `xelatex file.tex` works already in a terminal line. So I want to make `C-c C-c` in `Emacs` be able to launch either `LaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`. Ideally, `XeLaTeX` should be added to the list of possible commands.

Here is the current [.emacs](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5695310/), could anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Say

```
M-x customize-group
```

and

```
tex-command
```

Then find the "Tex Command List" option. From there you can introduce new AUCTeX commands.

However, AUCTeX is meant to be used a little differently. Instead of creating a separate `XeLaTeX` command, you can do

- `M-x TeX-engine-set` followed by `xetex` **or**
- `(TeX-engine-set 'xetex)` in lisp code **or**
- `Command | TeXing Options | Use XeTeX engine` in the menu bar

(the three methods are equivalent).

After that the `LaTeX` command will run xelatex instead of latex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that works... But how could I set `Use XeTeX engine` as default? I guess I still need to modify `.emacs`.

Comment: The default can be changed by `M-x customize-variable` and then `TeX-engine`. You can also call `(setq TeX-engine 'xetex)` in some hook, but be aware that the `TeX-engine` variable automatically becomes buffer-local in that case.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer - saved me a whole bunch of trouble... - for me I could just go to <<Command>> then  <<Texing Options>>

Comment: Is there a way to do the menu bar Command > TeXing Options > Use XeTeX engine without the menu bar, which I have hidden by default? Thanks!

Comment: `M-x TeX-engine-set` followed by `xetex` (or `(TeX-engine-set 'xetex)` in lisp code). You can also open the menu `F10` (the default binding for `menu-bar-open`) and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

A more local way to specify the `TeX-engine` is to append the following text to the very end of your `.tex` file. This will set `TeX-engine` to `xetex` for the current file only.

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

#### Edit in reply to comment

The same answer was given here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450955/90321, but that answer also shows how to call `Tex-engine` with command line arguments, by adding another line to the local variables:

```
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
```

Comment: How can I use this same lines to pass extra arguments? I need to pass `-shell-espace`

Comment: @AlexandreRademaker, I edited the answer regarding your question.

Comment: @leitungswasser Great answer! Also wondering, how can I set this up so that only certain specific project is compiled with XeLaTeX, while the remaining ones are still handled with pdflatex? I have a lot of files in the intended project so I don't really want to change the bottom text of each single file.

Comment: To answer my own question: of course, simply use local variables (```add-dir-local-variable``` and then ```TeX-engine```).